# How to get a number from a string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which have following pattern. String will always remain same. Just numbers will be different

```
Showing Results (1 – 15 of 96,831)
```

I want to extract `96,831` from that string. I want to do this with regex. What can be regex for that? I have tried a way where I am using two regex but still not getting required number.

```
"Showing Results (1 – 15 of 96,831)".replace(/[a-zA-Z\(\)]+/g, '').replace(/(\d+ – \d+)/g, '')
```

Its output is as follow. This output contains spaces which are not required.

```
"    96,831"
```

I want a way to do this in python. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You do not seem to need any regex here. Split and trim the last entry from the `)`. Is it really Python? Your code is JS.

Comment: Also, why *I want to use this regex in python* if it *still not getting required number*?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry for unclear statement. I mean I want a way in python to do this as if someone want to give example, he can give in python.

Comment: You clearly don't need a regex here (Assuming all the required strings will be of same format). The answer by @Iron Fist can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clear case where you should avoid regex as it just needs simple `strip` and `split`, like so:

```
>>> s = 'Showing Results (1 – 15 of 96,831)'
>>> num = s.split()[-1]
'96,831)'
>>> num.strip(')')
'96,831'
```

Or, using `str.rstrip`:

```
>>> num = s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[-1]
>>> num
'96,831)'
>>> num.strip(')')
'96,831'
```

But if you insist on using regex, then this pattern might do the job for you:

```
>>> import re
>>> nums = re.findall(r'\d+,?\d*', s)
['1 ', '15 ', '96,831']
>>> nums[-1]
'96,831'
```

And if you want to convert it to `float` don't forget to replace `,` with `.`:

```
>>> num
'96,831'
>>> 
>>> num = num.replace(',','.')
>>> num
'96.831'
>>> float(num)
96.831
```

Comment: If the string has `hello 6180 9 hello` it returns `'6180 9'` as a result (which should not be the case right?). So the `regex` you have used is kind of hard coded for the string.

Comment: @KartheekPalepu...This is a very general case and OP has to add more details to his requirement, I'm just providing a general purpose solution for him...that's all.

Comment: Plus your example is different than OP's one, which is way I said...OP has to provide more details.

Comment: Okay Great. I was just curious how a global regex looks like which suites for all input strings.

Comment: Thanx for detailed answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

One compact way of doing it without regex:

```
str = "Showing Results (1 – 15 of 96,831)"
print str.split(" ")[-1].strip(")")
```

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** I assume regex is necessary.

```
import re

print (re.findall(re.compile(u'of ([0-9,]+)'), u"Showing Results (1 – 15 of 96,831)")[0].replace(",", ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all of your test strings share the same format you can simply do:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = "\d+,\d+"
>>> pattern = re.compile(regex)
>>> str = "Showing Results (1 – 15 of 96,831")
>>> pattern.findall(str)
['96,831']
```